# SQL - Selecting data that is the same in multiple rows for a particular key

Tags: mysql

I have a dataset like below:

```
KEY     USER     STEP
---------------------
123     Geoff    1
123     Geoff    2
123     John     3
456     Jane     1
456     Jane     2
456     Jane     3
456     Jane     4
```

What I need to do is select the KEY where the USER is the same in all steps (there can be between 1 to 5 steps in the dataset). So in the example above I need the query to return KEY 456.
Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of comparing with `min(user)` and `max(user)`, you can do this as well:

```
SELECT tablename.key
FROM tablename
GROUP BY tablename.key HAVING count(DISTINCT d.user) = 1;
```

`count(DISTINCT d.user)` should be more descriptive for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
select key
from table t
group by key
having min(user) = max(user);
```

Note:  `key` and `user` are both keywords.  You may have to use backticks (or hopefully your actual column names are different).